# Sphericty axis and thrust axis

Tags: experimental-physics

I read a paper about the detection of the gluon at DESY in the 1979. There are described two methods of evaluating the results.
I do understand that jets are measured and the momentum is pretty important. But I wonder what it means by "with respect to the sphericity axis". I can not find any definition of a sphericity axis.
I hope someone else can help.

Comment: have a look https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.88.032004

Comment: also I remembered this  https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0370269379906026?token=29F1B874A5001D44BC6A032B3979A3D08BEBC1E7AA388D4A3DC538E12274A5AD40E9F8221EB1BFF7D07E3BA4B26F8CC0&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20210613142254  The theorists called it spherocity  forty years ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sphericity axis is the direction about which the total squared transverse momentum of all the observed particles is minimum.

This is easy to determine: you take the 3 by 3 matrix of the sum of the cartesian products of the particle momenta with themselves and diagonalise it. It's the analogy of the inertia tensor.

Spherocity is slightly different: it minimises the sum of the absolute transverse momenta.

The thrust axis is the one that maximises the sum of the total absolute momenta along the axis.

Thrust and spherocity require a numerical minimisation but are 'infra-red safe' in that if a (massless) particle splits into two they do not change, whereas the sphericity does. So sphericity is easy to calculate experimentally but messy to predict theoretically.